# What would happen if the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment was both observed and unobserved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-eraser

[image]

What I was wondering is if this experiment was conducted, but two people chose the results. The two people would be completely isolated with no knowledge of eachother, and would each choose to observe or not observe the data. Would the results instantly be those of a particle for both if one person chose to observe the slits, or would they each get the results they chose, making the results relative to the individual person.

Answer (score 1):

The results of the quantum eraser do not depend on whether the information is observed by someone.  It is sufficient that the which-way information has been copied, be it onto a single quantum particle or into the mind of an observer.

Similarly, the results the observers see would be the same regardless of what the other observer does, when he/she does it, or if there is only one observer.  (Of course, the results are statistically distributed, so no prediction can be made for a single observation, but who measures and when or even if they measure doesn't affect their distribution.)

Comment: I do understand that, and thanks for the response, but that doesn't really answer my question. If you have any other input though that may answer it I'ld be glad to hear it.

Comment: @user168804  Updated.  What is is about the quantum eraser that people keep on asking all these questions?